# Generating vampire numbers for a free range in Java (For big ranges)

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

A vampire number is a natural number with an even number of digits, that can be factored into two integers. These two factors are called the fangs, and must have the following properties:

they each contain half the number of the digits of the original number
together they consist of exactly the same digits as the original number
at most one of them has a trailing zero

> An example of a Vampire number and its fangs: 1260 : (21, 60)

This is a simple code to generate vampire numbers 4 digits . How to modify this to generate vampire numbers for large numbers (100000,200000) efficiently

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Vampire
{
    final static int START = 11, END = 1000;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[] kChar, checkChar;
        String kStr, checkStr;
        int k;
        for(int i=START; i<END; i++) {
                for(int i1=i; i1<100; i1++) {

                    k = i * i1;

                    kStr = Integer.toString(k);
                    checkStr = Integer.toString(i) + Integer.toString(i1);



                    kChar = kStr.toCharArray();
                    checkChar = checkStr.toCharArray();

                    Arrays.sort(kChar);
                    Arrays.sort(checkChar);

                    if(Arrays.equals(kChar, checkChar) ) {
                        System.out.println(i + " * " + i1 + " = " + k);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is more suited to helping solve a small, specific problem, and is not simply a code-writing service where you give a problem statement and get an algorithm back. Please show us some of the approaches you tried, and your specific concerns with them.

Comment: added a code segment that needs to be modified for big number ranges !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this, which is basically the same as your approach,
just adjusted for slightly "larger" ranges.

On my pc it takes less than 1 seconds to fully scan all vampiric numbers in the 8 digit range and around 80 seconds for the 10 digit range. Anything beyond that takes a while ...

I have also added in the elimination of two fangs with trailing zeroes, which was not mentioned in your definition.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Vampire {

    final static int START = 10, END = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int fangA = START; fangA < END; fangA++) {

            String sFangA = String.valueOf(fangA);
            boolean trailingZeros = sFangA.endsWith("0");           
            int max = (int) Math.min(END, Math.pow(10, sFangA.length()));

            for (long fangB = fangA; fangB < max; fangB++) {

                long candidate = fangA * fangB;
                if (candidate % 9 == (fangA + fangB) % 9) {  

                    String sCandidate = String.valueOf(candidate);
                    String sFangB = String.valueOf(fangB);

                    if ((trailingZeros && sFangB.endsWith("0")) == false) {

                        char[] cVampire = sCandidate.toCharArray();
                        Arrays.sort(cVampire);

                        char[] cFangs = (sFangA + sFangB).toCharArray();
                        Arrays.sort(cFangs);

                        if (Arrays.equals(cVampire, cFangs)) {
                            System.out.println(sFangA + " * " + sFangB + " = " + sCandidate);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You might also want to check this [`page`](http://www.primerecords.dk/vampires/index.htm). It contains an optimized `c` program and a description of the algorithm it is based on.

But it still took around 19 hours to compute all 14-digits vampiric numbers (back in 2002, might be a bit faster nowadays on a decent pc).

---

I noticed that the result for `(fangA + fangB) % 9` always seems to be either 0 or 4. I image that it has something to do with the assumption from `Pete Hartley`, but I can't really explain that.

Using that knowledge allows one to optimize the inner loop, and skipping 7 out of 9 possible values. The results up to the 10 digits numbers were identical (I didn't test further than that), the time improvement is around 15% (~68 seconds).

[The linked page mentions only 6 out 81 pairs need to be tested, but I haven't figured out how to apply that]

---

**EDIT:**

`START` and `END` describe the search range for each fang (and not the vampire number). If you want to only have a specific range of vampire numbers then apply that to the results you get here. Unless you have a efficient way to generate the valid permutations of a `vampire number` this approach seems to be much faster.

`Math.pow(10, sFangA.length())` is used to limit the search in the inner loop to fangB's with the same number of digits as fangA.

I've added the `Math.min` to ensure that fangB's range is also between `START` and `END` (before that fangB's range was always the complete fangA's-digit range).

Comment: great ! can you tell me how/why you come with this: int max = (int) Math.pow(10, sFangA.length());

Comment: Also my problem statement goes like this . given a range ,find the vampire numbers within the given range and their fangs. I guess the program you gave prints the fangs in the given range. That is fangs from START value to END value

Comment: I edited the answer to reply to your questions and fixed that 'fangB' was not limited by the `END` value.

Comment: @Skadoosh: I've seen that you tried to edit the answer, but it was rejected. Of course you can provide `start` and `end` as parameters to a `new` method. If you have a counter example (a vampiric number and a pair of fangs) for my assumption that the mod 9 value always is 0 or 4, provide it here and I remove these parts myself.

Comment: just thought that the page link you provided gave most of the details :-)